# @Media not working like I thought it should

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am learning about responsive design and @media is not working in the manner that I thought it should.  I have a subnav bar.  Here is the css:

```
.subnav-fixed {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  border-color: #d5d5d5;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .subnav-fixed {
    top: 61;
  }
}
```

When my page is under 767px, then I want the top to drop to 61px.  This is not happening.  The @media is after the .subnav class.  More than being told how to make this work, I would like to understand what is happening.  Any help or links would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@media all and (max-width:767px){
 .subnav-fixed {
    top: 61px;
  }
}
```

Added `all and` and also you just wrote `top: 61;` So, I added `px` at the end